# Is this freeze on Windows 10 a hardware issue?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, hardware-failure

I have experienced a one minute freeze on my up-to-date Windows 10 Education Edition. The question is if it is a hardware or software issue. The notebook is an older HP ProBook 4730s. Comprehensive HW/SW configuration from AIDA64 is [here](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B5y_o6yDHrmNNUF5amg3MUdpQ0k).

This is from Event viewer -> Windows logs -> Application:

```
The program explorer.exe version 10.0.10240.16431 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
 Process ID: 10c8
 Start Time: 01d125b8729610ff
 Termination Time: 0
 Application Path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
 Report Id: f60e6932-91c5-11e5-9bf4-9cb70d6a1bc7
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This is from Security and Maintenance control panel:

```
Description
A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   explorer.exe
Application Version:    10.0.10240.16431
Application Timestamp:  55c9bd76
Hang Signature: 17c4
Hang Type:  33554432
OS Version: 10.0.10240.2.0.0.256.121
Locale ID:  1051
Additional Hang Signature 1:    17c4817c1556eeda1cddaca120ca624a
Additional Hang Signature 2:    331c
Additional Hang Signature 3:    331c88d4b6b0027af1ffe45ab7c0ade5
Additional Hang Signature 4:    17c4
Additional Hang Signature 5:    17c4817c1556eeda1cddaca120ca624a
Additional Hang Signature 6:    331c
Additional Hang Signature 7:    331c88d4b6b0027af1ffe45ab7c0ade5

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  f43cfbf52b52bdf16610e73b4e07e23d (128895979238)
```

Comment: What I see here is a explorer crash, the explorer restarts itself. Explorer crashes are more often software issues if you were not having any other crashes or problems other than that. Hmm, hardware that would cause explorer crashes, a disk failing, ram problem, bad overclocks.  In software , some stupid context menu item that doesnt behave, any hooks to the explorer, or additional 3rd party programs that hooked into the shell.   For hardware one could (mostly) exclude it is if passed prime torture test, and memtest86.  For software use autoruns or something to discover bad software.

Comment: Plus any file integrity issues or the explorer itself, and its parts and pieces.  >SFC /scannow . More rare but possible driver problems, especially relating to I/O , usb items, auto run crap, not usually gpu and net stuff , unless using shared and networked resources. .  check the Event logs also, for any correleating program that crashed around the same moments , taking explorer down with it. Or programs that are hooked into it, that are showing as "not-respending".

Comment: There was a Firefox crash a few hours beforehead. No event has happened immediately before the explorer crash though.

Comment: I also have some serious overheating issues.

Comment: An overheat with an intel processor would just throttle usually and not cause a crash of any sort.  even though overheated components are more likely to "change data". Many laptops are overheating any time they do heavy work, yet far less of them are crashing an explorer :-)  prime95 beating a throttling computer would show if the cpu/ram starts changing data instead of just throttling down. Although it is a mean thing to do it, true torture, it would still reveal if the things flaw when working hard.

Comment: If you have overheating issues, then you have answered your own question.